# Filemap readding issues

Tags: memory, file-mapping, filemap

I Have two programs Dr1 and C1. They share information using a Filemap (which basically is two arrays, one for floats one for Integers). I use this programs to  a flow measure process which is reapeatly like 100 hunders times a day.
The problem is that sometimes the data shared by Dr1 cant be read correctly by C1.

I write the data from Dr1 to the filemap, then Dr1 read the same registry to be sure that is written ok.
Then C1 read the data, it reads two registry which are VolNat and VolNet. Difference between  VolNat has to be betwen +/- 10% of Volnet. So C1 checks that relation when reads the data. If data is wrong I wait a second and read again. I repeat 3 times.
So 1% of the times, C1 doesnt read the data correctly, even  if I read it again. A estrange fact  is that Always is VolNat the bad data.
I am using windows 2003 server, runing under a virtual machine. The host is like 10 years old.
I wonder what can be causing that situation, can be a bug of windows? I have no idea how to fixed or what test I have to do to find the problem...

I have log all the part of the process, to be sure where the problem is located